# primefaces dialog buttons

Tags: jsf, button, primefaces

I need to put extra buttons in the dialog box in Primefaces.
For example I want to put some buttons like Save Update Close instead of just close button.

Is there any way to do that?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I want to put extra buttons near the close X icon on the header of dialog.But I dont know how, that button is built in. @JaqenH'ghar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p:dialog ... >
    <f:facet name="header">
            <p:commandButton value="Hello button"></p:commandButton>
    </f:facet>
```

But it will appear on the left side of dialog header. You will need to override Primefaces CSS:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title
```

it has `float: left;` attribute.
Also use some browser developer tool like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to fix CSS. Good luck.